Pulling data from HTTP request in Power Automate Desktop

I am trying to pull data from Power Automate Desktop from an HTTP Request. It is simple in a cloud flow but very difficult in Desktop.
I converted the HTTP Request to a JSON Custom Object and am still struggling with syntax. The documentation says one thing, but I read on a forum that the syntax was recently changed. Does anyone know how to access the data in a custom object?

We need more information to help you. Please share the HTTP Request data and the converted JSON you have.

you can pass the json to a PAD flow from a cloud flow using the dektop flows connector

Thank you both for the help, I will definitely try that!
